# Add object to listbox and use different string representations depending on the listbox?

Tags: vb.net, object, listbox, tostring

I have a coupple of listboxes with the same object type in all of them, the problem i have is that i dont want the object displayed with the same ToString() method in all of the listboxes. Is there a way to solve this?

At the moment im adding strings to the listboxes and then i use the selected string to search a list of objects for the correct one but i dont like that solution at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose to have a class for Employees like this one:

```
Public Class Employee
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property FirstText As String
    Public Property SecondText As String
    ' and go on with other properties
    ....
End Class
```

Now when you populate your listboxes, you set the DisplayMember and ValueMember of your listboxes to two different property of Employee

```
Dim myList As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
myList.Add(New Employee() With {.ID = 1, .FirstText = "John Doe", .SecondText = "Doe John"})
myList.Add(New Employee() With {.ID = 2, .FirstText = "Mark Ross", .SecondText = "Ross Mark"})

ListBox1.DataSource = myList
ListBox2.DataSource = myList

ListBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstText"

ListBox2.ValueMember = "ID"
ListBox2.DisplayMember = "SecondText"
```